# Spring service implementation by environment property

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, service, settings

I have a service interface

```
interface ImageSearchService {
   // methods...
}
```

And I have 2 implementations:

```
@Service
class GoogleImageSearchImpl implements ImageSearchService {
   // methods...
}

@Service
class AzureImageSearchImpl implements ImageSearchService {
   // methods...
}
```

And I have a controller to use one of the both:

```
@Controller
ImageSearchController {

    @Autowired
    ImageSearchService imageSearch; // Google or Azure ?!?

}
```

How can I use a [Environment API](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) to set the right one implementation?

If environment property is `my.search.impl=google` spring needs to use `GoogleImageSearchImpl`, or if environment `my.search.impl=google` spring needs to use `AzureImageSearchImpl`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve this using Spring Profiles.

```
interface ImageSearchService {}

class GoogleImageSearchImpl implements ImageSearchService {}

class AzureImageSearchImpl implements ImageSearchService {}
```

Note that the `@Service` annotation has been removed from both the implementation classes because we will instantiate these dynamically.

Then, in your configuration do this:

```
<beans>
  <beans profile="azure">
    <bean class="AzureImageSearchImpl"/>
  </beans>
  <beans profile="google">
    <bean class="GoogleImageSearchImpl"/>
  </beans>
</beans>
```

If you use Java configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("azure")
public class AzureConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public ImageSearchService imageSearchService() {
    return new AzureImageSearchImpl();
  }
}

@Configuration
@Profile("google")
public class GoogleConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public ImageSearchService imageSearchService() {
    return new GoogleImageSearchImpl();
  }
}
```

When running the application, select the profile you want to run as by setting the value for the variable `spring.profiles.active`.  You can pass it to the JVM as `-Dspring.profiles.active=azure`, configure it as an environment variable, etc.

[Here](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-profiles) is a sample application that shows Spring Profiles in action.

Comment: You can just put `@Profile` on your `@Service` bean and then it will be only loaded the desired environment. Is easier then creating configuration classes or xml files for it...

Comment: Thanks @Marten, that is definitely much simpler.

Comment: @M.Deinum, can I define a default profile when there is no one setted?

Comment: Yes, there is a default profile called `default`.  You can use one of your implementations as the default as `@Profile({ "azure", "default" }) @Service class AzureImageSearchImpl {}` or provide a completely different default implementation as `@Profile("default") @Service class DummyImageSearchImpl {}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Conditional also

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @Conditional(LinuxCondition.class)
  public MyService getMyLinuxService() {
    return new LinuxService();
  }
}
```

Example given : [Spring choose bean implementation at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350865/spring-choose-bean-implementation-at-runtime)